# Is there a way to read files using arrow from the remote server in c++?

Tags: apache-arrow, apache-arrow-cpp

Reading CSV or Parquet files from local fs is very easy, but it seems that arrow does not support reading files from a remote server given its ip. Is there a way to achieve this? e.g. read a subset columns of a Parquet file from a remote server (path is like "ip://path/to/remote/file"). Thanks.

Comment: If your remote server exposes an S3 compatible API then you can use the S3 filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

`pyarrow.dataset.dataset()` has a `filesystem` argument through which it supports many remote file systems.

See the [Arrow documentation for file systems](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/filesystems.html). An `fsspec` file system can also be passed in, of which there are [very many](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#built-in-implementations).

For example, if your Parquet file is sitting on a web server, you could use the `fsspec` HTTP file system:

```
import pyarrow.dataset as ds                                                                                                                                                          
import fsspec.implementations.http
http = fsspec.implementations.http.HTTPFileSystem()
d = ds.dataset('http://localhost:8000/test.parquet', filesystem=http)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue for this if you would like to contribute or follow development: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-7594

(By 'remote server' I assume you mean over HTTP(s) or similar. If you're looking for a custom client-server protocol, check out [Arrow Flight](https://arrow.apache.org/blog/2019/10/13/introducing-arrow-flight/).)

Comment: Thanks! Yes it can be over HTTP(s) and formats the file (csv/parquet) into arrow at client side, different from flight which does this at file-server side. For parquet this can potentially reduce data transfer as it's compressed during transfer.

Comment: It can be done through the `fsspec` HTTP file system. (I've added an example for this.) Do you know if there is any advantage in implementing ARROW-7594 over using `fsspec`?

Comment: A 'native' Arrow filesystem doesn't have to call back into Python. For things like Dataset which do parallel I/O, this can avoid potential bottlenecking on the GIL. (Also, as an Arrow maintainer, a 'native' filesystem would be accessible to R as well.)